# How to check if empty list is inside of inside of a dictionary inside of list and remove that dict object from list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [{'email':['test@test.com']},{'email':['test1@test1.com']},{'email':[]},{'email':['test2@test2.com']}]
```

How do I remove the entire dictionary where the empty list is present inside the dictionary so lst looks like this:

```
lst = [{'email':['test@test.com']},{'email':['test1@test1.com']},{'email':['test2@test2.com']}]
```

I tried this;

```
if not any(d['email'] == '' for d in lst):
    print('not there')
```

But i dont even hit the print statment, not sure how to find this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be as simple as:

```
lst = [d for d in lst if d["email"]]
```

Or, if you want to avoid a KeyError if the 'email' key is missing:

```
lst = [d for d in lst if d.get("email", [])]
```

> For more information about list comprehension: [list-comprehensions-in-python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: both of your answers give me this output `[{'email': []}]`

Comment: sorry, I wrote a little too quick, fixed

Comment: I like this answer because it works better in the try i am usng

Answer (score 0):

i rephrase your problem quickly as far as i under stood it :

"How to delete a dictionary from a list if the value for the key="email" is an empty List ?"

```
for i, dictionary in enumerate(lst): 
    if not dictionary["email"]: 
        lst.pop(i)
```

here lst is the provided list:

[{'email':['test@test.com']},{'email':['test1@test1.com']},{'email':[]},{'email':['test2@test2.com']}]

The result is:

```
print(lst)
>>> [{'email':['test@test.com']},{'email':['test1@test1.com']},{'email':['test2@test2.com']}]
```

More Infos to the list method pop [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm)

Hope this helps.

Comment: that did it ! the rephrasing even helps me

Comment: I claryfied that the list we started with changed and not the result of the pop() method is the desired output.